# How to use Bash or Regex to remove English characters?

Tags: regex, bash

How can one delete lines which have English letters and or numbers, but keep Chinese? There are about ~10,000 lines per document.

Example input:

```
1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
古老的故事
12345


consectetur adipiscing elit
567
8910
美丽的歌谣
美女与野兽
```

Example output:

```
1
古老的故事
12345


567
8910
美丽的歌谣
美女与野兽
```

For some reason Chinese characters get matched when using sed. Given the following command notice that, in the output, the Chinese characters under the "1" are missing. I'm not sure why that is. But, I need to keep them.

```
sed '/[a-zA-Z]/d' file
```

Input

```
 1
 很久很久以前
 Once upon a time

 2
 在一个遥远地方
 in a faraway land
```

Current Output

```
1

2
在一个遥远地方
```

Comment: Show your attempts.

Comment: What do you expect for lines that contain both English and Chinese characters inside the same line?

Comment: n.m. - I've edited the post to show my attempt

@Fred There are almost no lines that contain both Chinese and English. It would be best to keep those lines, but its okay to get rid of them since its probably easier that way.

Comment: Try this: `LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8" sed '/[a-zA-Z]/d' file`

Comment: Still, same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an attempt at a solution that will not get rid of lines with both English and Chinese characters, and also keep lines that contain no English letters (e.g. to keep lines that are made up of only separators, newlines, etc.).

```
awk '/[^\x00-\x7F]/ || !/[A-Za-x]/'
```

I am not an `awk` expert by any stretch of the imagination (any constructive suggestions are welcome), but this expression should keep lines that either :

1. Contain any character not inside the ASCII range
2. Contain no letter from the alphabet

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in Javascript, try this.

```
var myString = '1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 古老的故事 12345';
myString = myString.replace ( /[a-zA-Z]/g, '' );
console.log(myString);
```

Take care of the extra spaces though.

Answer (score 0):

Why not `grep` with the invert-match flag to a temporary file?

```
grep -v '[A-Za-z]' file.txt > tmp && mv tmp file.txt
```